# How to forbid Mouse in Qt 4.8.6?

Tags: qt, mouse, touchpad

Because I want to test TouchPad of laptop, then I should forbid the Mouse device. But I don't know how to forbid Mouse in Qt 4.8.6. Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably reimplement the `QWidget` event handlers:

- [`QWidget::mousePressEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)
- [`QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent)
- [`QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent)
- [`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent)

and simply return from all of them.